# Website not working in Internet Explorer and Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, explorer

My site is currently live under a test site [here](http://www.example.littlebearmedia.com) (a sub-domain of another domain I own). I thought it was ready to transfer the site onto it's proper URL location but having done some last minute checks I have realized that it does not work properly in Internet Explorer and is even worse in Firefox!

The homepage in particular is all out of sorts. I'm not sure why this is as the site was based on a popular Elegant Themes theme called Evolution so i thought it would be compatible with all browsers.

This is a huge disappointment to me as being new to website design /development I have no idea how to fix these issues. If anyone is able to offer some insight and advice it would be incredibly appreciated as I'm at a loss.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  I see the site look identical in Chrome and Firefox... it might help to clearly describe the difference between what you expect to see and what you actually see.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, there is more files download (47) than in firefox/IE (42). With my konqueror I don't have any problem.

So its look like security issues. For somes resons IE/Firefox don't want to dowload file that are not where the want.

If I'm right, a solution could be to put all files (even thoses of wordpress) and all ressources on servers where all security problems have been solved.